# Novice learning RoR: Trying to run Rails server but getting odd output in terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-10.10, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to run Rails Server in Ubuntu 10.10 terminal.  But I get an output completely different from that shown in my tutorial:

```
Usage:
rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
-r, [--ruby=PATH]           # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                          # Default: /home/rinki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
-d, [--database=DATABASE]   # Preconfigure for selected database (options: 
mysql/oracle  /postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db)
                          # Default: sqlite3
-b, [--builder=BUILDER]     # Path to an application builder (can be a filesystem path  
or URL)
-m, [--template=TEMPLATE]   # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path 
or URL)
  [--dev]                 # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails   
checkout
  [--edge]                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails  
repository
  [--skip-gemfile]        # Don't create a Gemfile
-O, [--skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
-T, [--skip-test-unit]      # Skip Test::Unit files
-J, [--skip-prototype]      # Skip Prototype files
-G, [--skip-git]            # Skip Git ignores and keeps

Runtime options:
-f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
-p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
-q, [--quiet]    # Supress status output
-s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
-v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit
-h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit

Description:
The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

Example:
rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your helpfulness!  Have taken suggestions and it's, finally, working.

Comment: How did you install Rails, and which version do you use? you can type in your console "rails -v" to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a project in the directory first?  It looks like you haven't.  Once you setup a project with `rails new` you will be able to run the rails server for the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run rails server type in your console "rails server", and if you want create a new project type in your console "rails new project_name"

Answer (score 0):

What version of Rails are you running?

In your terminal type 'rails -v'. If you do not have version 3 then the 'rails new app_name' syntax will not work for this was changed in Rails 3.

Try updating Rails and trying again: 'gem update rails'.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best documentation you can get for ubuntu on Rails. It will help you set up everything pretty easily :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails

Comment: No, it's not the best documentation, because it recommends using `apt-get` to install the whole environment.  This just isn't a good idea, for reasons given [here](http://www.ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/).  Instead, follow the instructions given in that article, and use RVM to manage your Rails environment.